# SQL Error when JOINing two tables created via two WITH statements- SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 4 tables: Users, Workouts, Exercises, and Results. A "User" posts "Results" for "Exercises" which are linked to a single "Workout". But when the user posts results, since there are multiple exercises, results for one workout can be linked with a unique "post_id". I would like to know how many total minutes a user exercised based on how many "post_ids" they provided which can be linked to the "Workouts" table where a "workout_length" column shows how many minutes each workout lasts. I would also like to add their total calories...calories are stored in an "exercises" table. Here is some sample data, where in this case the workout (workout_id=1) has two exercises and has a workout_length of 1 minute...each exercise burns 1 calorie per rep.

Results:

```
user_id| workout_id| post_id| exercise_id| number_of_reps|
-------+-----------+--------+------------+---------------+
    123|         1 |       1|          1 |             18|
    123|         1 |       1|          2 |             29|      
    123|         1 |       2|          1 |             15|
    123|         1 |       2|          2 |             30|
    123|         1 |       3|          1 |             20|
    123|         1 |       3|          2 |             28|
-------+-----------+--------+------------+---------------+
```

Workouts:

```
workout_id| workout_length|
----------+---------------+
         1|              1|
----------+---------------+
```

Exercises:

```
workout_id| exercise_id| calories|
----------+------------+---------+
         1|           1|        1|
         1|           2|        1|  
----------+------------+---------+
```

Users:

```
user_id| first_name| last_name|
-------+-----------+----------+
    123|       John|       Doe| 
-------+-----------+----------+
```

I am able to successfully generate two separate tables...one for summing total minutes and another for summing total calories; however, I need to get these totals all in one table and GROUP BY users. Below are the queries I used:

Total Calories:

```
SELECT SUM(calories * reps) as total_cals, user_id, first_name, last_name 
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN exercises on results.exercise_id = exercises.id        
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts on results.workout_id = workouts.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY user_id, first_name, last_name
ORDER BY total_cals DESC
```

Total Minutes:

```
SELECT SUM(workout_length) as total_mins, first_name, last_name, user_id
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(results.post_id), users.first_name, users.last_name, workouts.workout_length 
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts ON results.workout_id = workouts.id)
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, user_id
```

Both of these queries work fine separately, but when I try and combine them into one query using WITH statements, SQLite3 throws an error saying the "workout_length column does not exist". I know it's a lot of stuff to look at...but any ideas?

```
WITH minute_table AS (SELECT SUM(workouts.workout_length) as total_mins, user_id 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(results.post_id), users.id 
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts ON results.workout_id = workouts.id) 
GROUP BY user_id), 
cals_table AS 
(SELECT SUM(calories * reps) as total_cals, user_id, first_name, last_name   
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN exercises ON results.exercise_id = exercises.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts ON results.workout_id = workouts.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY user_id, first_name, last_name) 
SELECT cals_table.first_name, cals_table.last_name, cals_table.total_cals, minute_table.total_mins 
FROM minute_table 
JOIN cals_table ON minute_table.user_id = cals_table.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look...unfortunately that did not work...I have edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Isn't table's name `Workouts` with a capital `W` ? In your edit, you have used a small `w` in table's name. Did you try with capital `W` ?

Comment: I tried with a capital W also and it didn't seem to make a difference...I don't think SQLite3 is case-sensitive from what I can tell...at least it doesn't matter when I use SQLite via my Ruby on Rails application.

Comment: Unless what you posted here does not align to actual code, I cannot see how your query fails as syntactically it reads fine. Curious, does one `SELECT` query in `WITH` work?

Comment: Yeah I just tried a simple `WITH mytable as (SELECT * FROM workouts) select workout_length from mytable` and it worked fine. I'll keep at it for now...thanks all.

Comment: I just got it...thanks for your help guys. I just needed to fiddle around a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...just needed to add "workouts.workout_length" to the first SELECT statement.

```
WITH minute_table AS (SELECT SUM(workout_length) as total_mins, user_id 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(results.post_id), workouts.workout_length, users.id as user_id
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts ON results.workout_id = workouts.id) 
GROUP BY user_id), 
cals_table AS 
(SELECT SUM(calories * reps) as total_cals, user_id, first_name, last_name   
FROM results 
LEFT OUTER JOIN exercises ON results.exercise_id = exercises.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN workouts ON results.workout_id = workouts.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on results.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY user_id, first_name, last_name) 
SELECT cals_table.first_name, cals_table.last_name, cals_table.total_cals, minute_table.total_mins 
FROM minute_table 
JOIN cals_table ON minute_table.user_id = cals_table.user_id
```